# Non Commutative Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

If $R$ is a commutative ring, so is $R[x].$

Is it necessary to take a commutative ring $R$ in order to construct something like $R[x]$ i.e. will $R[x]$ still be a ring if $R$ is not commutative?

Comment: idk, try constructing it and see what happens

Comment: You can define a polynomial ring with any ring $R$ commutative or otherwise. For example, you can have a polynomial ring over the quaternions $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: @AnuragA Could you please give some references for that?

Comment: If $x$ doesn't commute with every element $\in R$ then the ring $R<x>$ generated by $R$ and the indeterminate $x$ isn't a polynomial ring since it contains elements such as $x ax$. What you can do is to embed $R$ in a larger ring $S$ and see the polynomials $\sum_j c_j x^j \in R[x]$ as functions $Z(S) \to  S$ where $Z(S)$ is the center, we now have $xax = ax^2$ and $R[x]$ is a polynomial ring. For example with the quaternions then $\Bbb{H}[x]$ is a ring of polynomial functions $\Bbb{R \to H}$. And for $b \in \Bbb{R}$ we have $p(b) = 0 \implies p(x)=q(x)(x-b)$.

Comment: If you know the construction of R[x], then you have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the polynomial ring $R[x]$: An element of $R[x]$ is a formal sum $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j$, modulo the equivalence relation that, if $m < n$ and $a_{m+1} = a_{m+2} = \cdots = a_n$, then $\sum_{j=0}^m a_j x^j$ and $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j$ are the same polynomial.

Addition is given by $\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j + \sum_{j=0}^n b_j x^j = \sum_{j=0}^n (a_j+b_j) x^j$, and multiplication is given by $\left( \sum_{i=0}^m a_i x^i \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^n b_j x^j \right) = \sum_{i=0}^m  \sum_{j=0}^n a_i b_j x^{i+j}$. It is straightforward to check that this defines a ring (with identity, not necessarily commutative).

The big difference with the commutative case is that evaluation of polynomials is not a map of rings. If $R$ is commutative and $\theta \in R$, then the map $f(x) \mapsto f(\theta)$ is a map of rings $R[x] \mapsto R$. (And, more generally, if $S$ is a commutative $R$-algebra and $\theta \in S$, then $f(x) \mapsto f(\theta)$ is a map of rings $R[x] \to S$.)

For non-commutative rings this isn't true! For example, let $R$ be the quaternions. We have $(x+i) (x-i) = x^2+1$, but $(j-i) (j+i) \neq j^2 +1 $. This makes polynomials a lot less useful when their coefficients are not commutative.