# Definition of polynomials, polynomial function and commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, noncommutative-algebra

When multiplying polynomials in a ring using the definition we get $(a_0,a_1,...)(b_0,b_1,...)=(c_0,c_1,..)$ where $\displaystyle c_n=\sum_{m=0}^{n}a_mb_{n-m}$ and $x$ is $x=(0,1,0,...)$. Now consider the ring of quaternions and the polynmial
$$ f(x)=x^2-(i+j)x+k 
$$
This polynomial can be factored a such
$$(x-i)(x-j)=(-i,1)(-j,1)=((-i)(-j),-i-j,1)=(k,-(i+j),1)=x^2-(i+j)x+k
$$
Using the definition.
Now if we try to expand $(x-i)(x-j)$ considering $x$ a quartenion we get
$$(x-i)(x-j)=x^2-xj-ix+ij
$$
This way $xj\neq jx $.

Also if we put in the value $x=i$ we get
$$
f(i)=i^2-(i+j)i+k=2k
$$
But if we use the factorazation for $x=i$ we get
$$
(i-i)(i-j)=0
$$
I think this happens because the definition of polynomials "implies" commutativity between $x$ and the coefficients under multiplication and when using the polynomial function this isn't always the case because $x$ becomes an element of the ring. If somebody could clear things out a bit for me i would be thankfull.

Comment: I think the factorization of polynomials (fundamental theorem of algebra) only applies to polynomial rings over integral domains. The quaternion ring is not an integral domain. And multiplications of polynomials should not be defined by the coefficients (which is indeed convenient for commutative polynomial rings).

Comment: I think you can still define polynomial rings over noncommutative rings, but you do lose the evaluation map and thus polynomial functions. See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294258/non-commutative-polynomial-ring).